# AJAX server mockup

Tags: java, ajax, design-patterns, architecture

I am having a Java applet developed on my behalf. The applet makes AJAX requests to a server. I have not written the server code yet.

Is there a design pattern I can use to mock the server responses, whilst the server is not yet ready, so that the applet can be developed and tested against this "mock server"?

Some sample code on how to implement the mockup server would be very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure if this suits your needs, but you can checkout a simple class I made for this purposes [here](https://github.com/fernandohur/nanohttpd/blob/master/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/MockHttpServer.java). Here is some sample code:

```
//let's say that when you GET to /users?id=2 the server should return the user with id 2
//first start the server on your favourite port
MockHttpServer server = new MockHttpServer(portNum);
server.start();

//We will add a mock response for every request we will do, so in this case, just one mock response
server.enqueueResponse(Status.OK, "application/json,"{\"user_id\":15,\"name\":\"paul\"}");

//now we will use curl or whatever to make the GET
curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/users?id=2

// we get the request object
Request req = server.getRequest();
assertEquals(req.getMethod(),"GET");
assertEquals(req.getParams().get("id"),"2")
```

Its still a work in progress but you can get an idea by reading the code on github. Hope it helps :)